# Postback cancel with error message

Tags: php, android-pay

I'm integrating *Google Wallet* with my website to buy and create a new user account.

In my postback (`php`) page, I create the account.

**If** account creation is **successful**, I respond to Google with a `200 OK` and the `orderId` to complete the purchase. This works fine.

*Here is my problem:*
**If** account creation is **unsuccessful**, I would like to cancel the purchase and tell the user *why* it was cancelled.

I have not seen anyone discuss how to do this.

Currently, I just `die()` or `exit()` the postback page, which effectively cancels the purchase (since no 200 or orderId is `echo`ed). Will Google wait for 10 seconds or cancel right away?

That doesn't actually tell the user why it was cancelled.

**How can I tell the user why the purchase was cancelled??** - like alert them with an error message
Is this even possible? Edit the sellerData so the client will process it upon error? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO - it'll likely be similar to the last step of verifying, server-side, typically on success ([see #6 in the diagram](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/)).

In this case, on *failure* , using an identifier *other* than the Google Order ID - e.g. something in the [`sellerData` field](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#jwt) since you won't get one (Order ID).

So this means you'll track "all types of orders" (aka like tracking "failed or abandoned carts") and check on the (failure) callback.

Hth...

---

**Update:**

On failure (or success for that matter), you will get your original `sellerData` [as shown here](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#failurehandler). So you could:

- add a "cart ID" (unique to *your app*)
- on failure callback, query your server for that "cart ID"
- and check on it's "status" (which could be the custom/specific error message)
- display that in UI so your user gets a friendlier/more specific message (as you deem fit)...

Note: failure callback will also be called if the user simply closes the window (not necessarily going through/proceed with transaction). So you could "filter" when to call your server - e.g. `POSTBACK_ERROR` based on above and not have to do so for all cases (debug it though, I haven't tried).

Added note: this depends on your definition of "account creation was not successful" - if this means "any" case (including server error on your end and you don't need to distinguish), then perhaps the server check/cart id is unnecessary (you could just key off of `POSTBACK_ERROR`)

Hth...

---

**Update 2**

**If** your use case requires you to distinguish reasons for *"account creation was unsuccessful"* (some business rule). Otherwise, if any/all, then you could probably handle this by checking the type of error in the [failure `response`](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#failurehandler) and not have to do any of this...

> is the cartId randomly generated?

Not so much "random", but unique

> If it is, I can pass it as a GET query parameter which I do upon success.

Based on your OP/question, unsure what it would mean for success. If I understood your question, you were looking for a way to better communicate to your users on *failures* .....

If you meant the final step for verification on **success**, you should use the Google Order ID.

> A second question: on failure, the server puts the orderId in the table because Google sends that info to the server. But the client is never given the response -> orderId on failure (only given on success)??

Yup, on "failures", including your choice to "cancel" based on some business rule and not responding properly (e.g. HTTP error instead of 200/OK), you won't get the order id in the *failure callback*. [Google will **cancel** the order](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/postback)

> *Important: If you specify a postback URL, your server must respond **promptly and correctly** to the HTTP POST messages that Google sends for each transaction. Otherwise, the transaction will be canceled.*

Your *failure handler* will be invoked, and that would be when you would use the unique cart ID - you're using this to "identify" the "cart"/"order" that you chose to "cancel" (instead of the Google Order ID)

Hope I'm not confusing you....just throwing idea/s...

Comment: Are you saying I should change the `sellerData` field to include an error code? If so, you can't since Google is selling the request JWT as the response JWT and you can't change it during the final transaction. I'm not sure if I'm getting that...

Comment: No, some "id" that identifies the "cart" (aka - like tracking abandoned "carts" where a "cart" has an "id"). You'll need to check "what type of error" (which you will have to create). Including an "error code" in `sellerData` won't do much - you can't really say "why" (specifically, vs. any other failure cause) - re: makes "no difference" from any other failure...does this make sense?

Comment: So a cart id will be sent back on success or error no matter what. I'll use that id to tell me something?

Comment: So I create a table containing purchases (which is always a good thing to do). I have columns containing important transaction information with the success/error info. Sounds great!

Comment: Quick question: is the cartId randomly generated? If it is, I can pass it as a GET query parameter which I do upon success.     A second question: on failure, the server puts the orderId in the table because Google sends that info to the server. But the client is never given the `response -> orderId` on failure (only given on success)?? Are we back to the original question?

Comment: So I generate a random and unique cart id for success and failure callbacks, located within the `sellerData`. The `orderId` just supplements the `cartId`, but is not the actual identifier. I store the `cartId` on the database. On success/failure, I can use that id to get information on the purchase. Thanks!